# How to make an equality test on an array

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am trying to aggregate values on an ID. I return them if they are all the same, but have to create another value 'C' if both are encountered.

> ```
> CREATE TABLE foo (
>     fooid int,
>     foocomm text
> ); 
>
> INSERT INTO foo (fooid,foocomm)
> VALUES (1,'A'); 
> INSERT INTO foo (fooid,foocomm)
> VALUES (1,'B'); 
> INSERT INTO foo (fooid,foocomm)
> VALUES (2,'A');
> ```

```
SELECT 
  CASE 

    WHEN array_remove(array_agg(foocomm),NULL) = {'A'} THEN 'A'
    WHEN array_remove(array_agg(foocomm),NULL) = {'B'} THEN 'B'
    WHEN array_remove(array_agg(foocomm),NULL) = {'A','B'} THEN 'C'
  END AS BAR

FROM foo
GROUP BY fooid;
```

It should yield

```
fooid,foocomm
1, 'C'
2, 'A'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
t=# SELECT fooid,
  CASE
    WHEN array_remove(array_agg(foocomm order by foocomm),NULL) = '{A}' THEN 'A'
    WHEN array_remove(array_agg(foocomm order by foocomm),NULL) = '{B}' THEN 'B'
    WHEN array_remove(array_agg(foocomm order by foocomm),NULL) = '{A,B}' THEN 'C'
  END AS BAR
FROM foo
GROUP BY fooid;
 fooid | bar
-------+-----
     1 | C
     2 | A
(2 rows)
```

your query works, just fix array text representation:

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/arrays.html#ARRAYS-INPUT

Comment: Thanks. I also found that an array could be written as array[value]

Comment: @Boodoo: you should sort your array aggregation: `array_agg(foocomm order by foocomm)` because `A,B` is a different array than `B,A`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name updated the answer - totally agree. thank you

Comment: What about in an update statement ? UPDATE foo
 SET foo3 = (CASE array_remove(array_agg(foocomm ORDER BY foocomm),NULL)
    WHEN  '{A}' THEN 'A'
    WHEN  '{B}' THEN 'B'
    WHEN  '{A,B}' THEN 'C'
 END);

Comment: `with c as (above_select_in_post) update .. set.. from c;`